# Could not authenticate you - twitter api v1.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I am trying to use the Twitter API to tweet, retweet, and upload images, while tweet works as intended, upload media don't work. more information below

the error appears at all the fetch request related to this function

Error:

```
{ errors: [ { code: 32, message: 'Could not authenticate you.' } ] }
```

I know whats the error is about, just asking this as I am confused why this would appear only in this function, as the auth info is correct and the same function used to create the headers work in another function

## Edit after a year

**Code was removed since the code did not have anything to do with the error**

Read my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the authorization headers, I had to generate them for each request.It was easy as creating a wrapper function that will take the request details (the needed ones) and output the headers

I have a Twitter API library written in typescript (unmaintained for now :/ )
That uses this, don't suggest completely using that, just take what you need from it

[Code Related](https://github.com/typicalninja493/tweets.ts/blob/master/src/rest/bucket.ts#L200)

^^
Above Links to - https://github.com/typicalninja493/tweets.ts/blob/master/src/rest/bucket.ts#L200